# horizontal scrollview isn't scrolling iOS

Tags: ios, swiftui, scrollview

I have a vertical scrollView and have 2 horizontal scrollviews on it which have buttons and navigationLinks inside them, the vertical scollview works properly, but it seems in horizontal scrollviews tapping action is in priority and I can't scroll them ( when I try to scroll, tapping button is called and scrollview isn't scrolled.
here is my code:

```
ZStack (alignment: .bottomTrailing){
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    TLMarqueeText(text: "All Venues", font: Font.SFProDisplay.uiFont(type: .bold, size: 28), leftFade: 10, rightFade: 10, startDelay: 1.5)
                        .foregroundStyle(Color(uiColor: .label))
                }//: HSTACK TITLE MARQUEE TEXT
                .padding(.top, safeAreaInsets.top)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
                    VStack {
                        VenuesSearchHearderView(searchText: $viewModel.searchText, customSortSelected: viewModel.customFilterSelected, nearYouPressed: viewModel.sortDataNearYou)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                            .padding(.bottom)

                        if let categories = viewModel.searchHandler.searchInitItems.filter({ $0.type == .categories }).first?.items {
                                 
                            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) { //<------- Issue is here
                                HStack {
                                   ForEach(items, id: \.uniqueId) { item in
                                          NavigationLink {
                                   ShowVenuesListCategorySelectedView(selectedCategory: CategoryModel(id: item.uniqueId, name: item.name ?? "", imageUrl: item.media?.imageUrl))
                                              .attachPartialSheetToRoot()
                                          } label: {
                                              CategoryTileItemView(mediaUrl: item.media?.imageUrl, title: item.name, imageFrameSize: 48)
                                              .frame(width: 150, height: 100)
                                              .cornerRadius(12, corners: .allCorners)
                                           }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                .frame(height: 100)
                                .padding(.bottom, 12)
                        }
                        
                        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) { // <------- issue is here
                            HStack {
                                Button {
                                    viewModel.searchHandler.selectedSearchInitItems = [:]
                                } label: {
                                    FilterChipView(name: "All", isShowChevron: false, selectedItems: 0)
                                }

                                ForEach(viewModel.searchHandler.searchInitItems, id: \.name) { initItem in
                                    if initItem.type != .categories {
                                        
                                        Button {
                                            viewModel.selectedFilterToShow = initItem
                                        } label: {
                                            FilterChipView(name: initItem.name ?? "", isShowChevron: true, selectedItems: viewModel.searchHandler.selectedSearchItemsCount(for: initItem.type.rawValue, component: initItem.component))
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }//: HSTACK SEARCH OPTION ITEMS
                            
                        } //: SCROLLVIEW AMINITIES AND FILTER OPTIONS
                        .padding(.bottom, 12)
                        
                        LazyVStack {
                            ForEach(viewModel.venues, id: \.id) { item in
                                NavigationLink {
                                    VStack {
                                        Text(item.name ?? "")
                                        Text("\(item.place?.location?.distance ?? 0) Distance")
                                    }
                                    
                                } label: {
                                    ListItemRichView(itemData: item, title: nil, showChevron: false)
                                        .frame(height: 266)
                                }
                            }
                        }//: VSTACK VENUE ITEMS
                        Spacer()
                            .frame(height: 80)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                
            }
           
            Button {
                self.viewModel.navigateToMapView = true
            } label: {
                FloatingRoundedButtonWithIconView(iconSystemName: "map", title: "Map view")
                    .padding(.trailing, 16)
                    .padding(.bottom, 100)
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
```